# Declaring an array of negative length

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, c99

What happens in C when you create an array of negative length?

For instance:

```
int n = -35;

int testArray[n];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    testArray[i]=i+1;
```

This code will compile (and brings up no warnings with -Wall enabled), and it seems you can assign to `testArray[0]` without issue.  Assigning past that gives either a segfault or illegal instruction error, and reading anything from the array says "Abort trap" (I'm not familiar with that one).  I realize this is somewhat academic, and would (hopefully) never come up in real life, but is there any particular way that the C standard says to treat such arrays, or is does it vary from compiler to compiler?

Comment: There is an unintended semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `for` statement, I think...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour, because it breaks a "shall" constraint:

**C99 §6.7.5.2:**

> If the size is an expression that is
>   not an integer constant expression...
>   ...each time it is evaluated it shall
>   have a value greater than zero.

Comment: +1, exactly the answer. But I find it quite disappointing that compilers are not yet able to do a static analysis of this sort of code and emit at least a warning. I tested also with `clang` and `-analyse`, not better.

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behavior, I believe, though don't quote me on that.

This gives the error `error: size of array 'testArray' is negative` in gcc:

```
int testArray[-35];
```

though, as you've seen:

```
int n = -35;
int testArray[n];
```

does not give an error even with both -Wall and -W.

However, if you use -pedantic flag, gcc will warn that ISO C90 forbids variable length array.

Comment: What does it actually do? I'm guessing it interprets it as unsigned so you get (MAX_INT-35)

Comment: @Martin Beckett: since it's undefined behavior, compilers are free to do anything, even if they're unreasonable behavior, since allocating a negative length array is a compilable nonsense. If I were to be allowed to redesign C, I'd make array length declaration and indexing an 'unsigned int', and compiler will be required to emit type error when 'signed int' is used for length or indexing operations.

Comment: the question was tagged C99, so the aspect of variable length array is ok from a standards point of view.

Comment: @MartinBeckett it just goes wild `sizeof(testArray) == -35 * sizeof(int)`;

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio erro message for [compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hxxst81%28VS.80%29.aspx), you can use -1 to say an empty array. It expects int and you are passing int, so no compiler error.