# ISO C90 forbids variable length array

Tags: c, variable-length-array

I'm dynamically calculating the size of an array. Something like:

```
void foo(size_t limit)
{
  char buffer[limit * 14 + 1];
}
```

But just GCC compiler says:

```
error: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘buffer’
```

searching on SO I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783369/866022):

**C99 §6.7.5.2:**

> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant
>   expression... ...each time it is evaluated it shall have a value
>   greater than zero.

So, I did the re-declaration of size limit type variable to:

```
void foo(const size_t limit)
```

But it continues to give warning for me. Is this a GCC bug?

Comment: Well, `C90 != C99`.

Comment: Declaring `size_t limit` as `const` doesn't change anything. It's still a variable length array since the size is run-time determined.

Comment: GCC is telling you that with the command-line options you are using, it compiles with respect to the C90 standard by default. The paragraph you quote is from C99. This is the cause of your problem, not the type of `limit`.

Comment: It should be noted that GCC itself supports Variable Length Arrays as a language extension, so this would work if you were not compiling in c99 mode - but it's not portable unless you will always be using a compiler that has such an extension or implements C99's VLAs.

Comment: Just invoke gcc with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`const`-qualifying a variable doesn't make it a compile-time constant (see C99 6.6 §6 for the defintion of an *integer constant expression*), and before the introduction of variable-length arrays with C99, array sizes needed to be compile-time constants.

It's rather obvious that `const`-qualify a variable doesn't make it a compile-time constant, in particular in case of function parameters which won't be initialized until the function is called.

I see the following solutions to your problem:

- compile your code as C99 via `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`
- allocate your buffer via `malloc()`
- use `alloca()` if available, which is the closest you can come to variable-length arrays with C90
- choose a maximum buffer size which is always used and fail if the given `limit` argument overflows

As a side note, even though C99 allows variable-length arrays, it's still illegal to use the value of an integer variable with static storage duration as size for an array with static storage duration, regardless of `const`-qualification: While there's nothing which prevents this in principle if the integer variable is initialized in the same translation unit, you'd have to special-case variables with visible defintion from those whose definition resides in a different translation unit and would either have to disallow tentative defintions or require multiple compilation passes as the initialization value of a tentatively defined variable isn't known until the whole translation unit has been parsed.

Answer (score 6):

`const` does not introduce a constant in C but a read-only variable.

```
#define SIZE 16
char bla[SIZE];   // not a variable length array, SIZE is a constant
```

but

```
const int size = 16;
char bla[size];   // C99 variable length array, size is a constant
```

Answer (score 3):

C90 doesn't allow variable length arrays. However, you can use the `c99-gcc` compiler to make this work.

You are compiling with `c90-gcc` but looking at C99 specifications.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not a bug. You can't use a VLA in C90. When you declared

```
const size_t limit
```

that is not a constant expression. A constant expression would be something like a literal value `666`.

Note that C differs significantly from C++ in this regard. Even a *constant* like this

```
const int i = 666;
```

is not a constant expression in C. This is the primary reason why constant values are typically declared with `#define` in C.

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation. out curiosity,why the C90 standard don't accept a constant expression like that I'm tried to use? because if I'm using const type, it mean than I can't modify it later,so,what is reason for forbid it? and C99 std,is otherwise,the int value don't need be at least of const type. sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: @Jack You don't have a constant expression. You have a `const` variable. A constant expression would be 42 or 66.

Answer (score 0):

As written in your question, this is from C99, not C90, you need to compile it against C99 to be able to use variable length arrays.

Comment: Or you may be able to use [alloca](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/alloca.3.html) instead.

Comment: Yup, yet dynamically allocating memory is something else.

Comment: Isn't alloca pretty much exactly the same as using a variable length array? (as it uses stack memory rather than the heap)

Answer (score 0):

A `const` qualified variable is not an integer constant expression in the sense of the standard. This has to be a literal constant, an enumeration constant, `sizeof` or some expression composed with these.

Switch to C99 if you may. The gcc option is `-std=c99` (or gnu99 if you want gnu extension.)