# %f in sprintf doesn't seem to work in the TI 84 CE online IDE

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

When I run this program on my calculator:

```
void main(void) {
    char *quot = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    char *rest = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(quot, "%d", 5);
    printText(quot, 0, 0);
    sprintf(rest, "%f", 2.03);
    printText(rest, 0, 1);
}
```

`printText` function for my TI 84 CE calculator:

```
void printText(const char *text, uint8_t xpos, uint8_t ypos) {
    os_SetCursorPos(ypos, xpos);
    os_PutStrFull(text);
}
```

This is the output on my calculator's LCD:

```
5
%
```

There is a percentage token instead of `2.03`, what is the reason behind this?

I have included these libraries:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <tice.h> // this is for my TI84
```

Comment: _You're running this on a calculator???_ __What???__ Sure thing there will be a lot of bugs and inconsistencies with the Standard.

Comment: Note: `void main(void){` and lack of `<stdio.h>` may be issues, but I suspect the real one is code lacks **explicit** FP math usage yet uses `"%f"`.  Insure compilation include the FP math library and/or do some FP math in the code.

Comment: Where (which library) is that sprintf coming from?

Comment: cemetech has an online IDE that supports the C language.  Documentation is available on github about the C backend for this project at https://github.com/CE-Programming support for floating point seems present, but may have problems.

Comment: Apparently the language (in particular the standard library implementation) you're working with is not actually C90 but some pseudo-C language the TI84 tools provide.

Comment: Just a side-note: why are you `malloc`'ing `quot` and `res`? It seems to me you could equally well use `char quot[10]` and `char res[10]`

Comment: Many implementations where memory is tight do not enable `"%f"` by default.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I used malloc instead of standard array initialisation because of: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234288/iso-c90-forbids-variable-length-array)

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks ! I didn't know that documentation existed ! I am indeed programming in that online IDE

Comment: I read the _[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234288/iso-c90-forbids-variable-length-array)_ you provided a couple of comments up, it seems to be talking about alternatives to VLAs (or the lack of prior to C99).  From what you have shown, VLA is not needed.  A regular C string (`char quot[10];`) would appear sufficient.  (as mentioned in Elias' comment.)

Comment: @Tom55555: the link talks about *variable length* arrays, i.e. the size is a variable expression. `char whateverthename[10]` is a fixed length array and is no problem in any C I know of.

Comment: @Tom55555: the question is *does the embedded version of `sprinf` support floating point conversions?*  I could not find an answer on their website, nor could I find the source to that library (but they do mention it to have an LGPL license),  You should ask on their forum.

Comment: @Tom55555: that would make sense if you, at some point, were using `realloc`. You're allocating a block of memory to store 10 char's. That can be done on the stack with a fixed length array: `char foo[10]`, that's different to VLA's

Answer (score 1):

`%f` is disabled due to memory constraints in the calculator. Float conversion is expensive. The dialect of C used is C89, which is the best C. Anyway, you can enable `%f` for your program by adding the following line in your makefile:

```
USE_FLASH_FUNCTIONS := NO
```

This will greatly increase the size of your binary however, so it is recommended to implement a custom limited version of `%f`. Alternatively, this code will do the same thing as `%f`, but copies the output to a character array.

```
void float2str(float value, char *str) {
    real_t tmp_real = os_FloatToReal(value);
    os_RealToStr(str, &tmp_real, 8, 1, 2);
}
```