# How can I edit this code so it compiles on ISO C90 and not just ISO C99?

Tags: c, c89

I'm currently running a shell project, I tried to compile the code using: `

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu89 *.c -o hsh
```

The compilation method is mandatory for my project. The code compiles on ISO C99 (-std=gnu99), but returned the error: `ISO C90 forbids variable length array` when I used the above compilation method. How can I edit this code instead so it compiles on ISO C90?

This is the code I tried:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 1;
int n = find_chars_number(s, sep, idx) + 1;
int array[n];
int o = 0;

array[0] = idx;
```

Error found on the line `int array[n];`
nb: find_chars_number is a function I invoked

Comment: You need to use dynamic memory allocation for the array, e.g. `int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));` Or you have to declare an array that's big enough for the worst case.

Comment: possible answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234288/iso-c90-forbids-variable-length-array)

Comment: If you decide to use `malloc`, be sure to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

Comment: Pre-C99, it was common to use `alloca` for this sort of thing.