# How to do static_assert with macros?

Tags: c++, macros, g++, static-assert, c++98

I have tried to use [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/174441/476681) to do a static assert, but I do not get a compilation error if I use it within a method of a template.

The example follows :

```
#include <iostream>

#define STATIC_ASSERT(expr, msg)               \
{                                              \
    char STATIC_ASSERTION__##msg[(expr)?1:-1]; \
    (void)STATIC_ASSERTION__##msg[0];          \
}

template <typename T >
class A
{
public:
  int foo(const int k )
  {
    // does not work
    STATIC_ASSERT( k > 9, error_msg );
    return k+5;
  }
};

int bar(const int k )
{
  // works fine
  //STATIC_ASSERT( k > 9, error_msg );
  return k+5;
}

int main()
{
  A<int> a;
  const int v = 2;

  std::cout<<a.foo(v)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<bar(v)<<std::endl;

  // works fine
  //STATIC_ASSERT( v > 9, error_msg );
}
```

I compiled it with g++ 4.7.2, with a warning that VLAs are not supported by c++ ISO :

```
g++ -Wall -g  -std=c++98 -Wextra -pedantic gvh.cpp
```

So, why the compilation doesn't fail when the STATIC_ASSERT is used within the template method? Is there a way to make it fail?

**NOTE** : I need a c++98 (maybe even c++03) solution, if possible only with macros.

Comment: Boost has a pre-C++11 static assert.

Comment: @chris Yes, I am aware of BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT, but it uses SFINAE to do a check.

Comment: In the answers and above there's good advice on which static assert mechanisms are around, but more fundamentally in your specific usage you're trying to assert on a function parameter - just because it's `const int` doesn't mean it's compile-time constant - that just means the function takes a copy of the runtime argument and won't allow the called code to modify it. You'll need to accept `k` as a template parameter (either for `A` or by making `A::foo` a `template <int K>`, or maybe fiddle with C++11 `constexpr`, to get the compile time check you're expecting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prior to C++11 I would normally do:

```
typedef int static_assert_something[something ? 1 : -1];
```

You can also look at [boost static assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html). But it is too bloated for my liking. It is easy to make things bigger, it is hard to make them any better.

Comment: Just for clarity(I always hated the typedef syntax): this works by trying to make a typedef to an array of size 1 or -1 depending on the truth value?

Comment: @TimSeguine Correct.

Comment: Careful, this will invoke undefined behavior if `something` is not a compile-time constant and the compiler supports variable-length arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783369/2192139

Comment: @Geier I would like to see an example.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin https://godbolt.org/z/ba59qz6PK No compile error on gcc or clang. If the (not-static) assertion is violated, the program returns `sizeof(...) = -4`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider something like [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html), although if that is unavailable to you you can try defining a template.

```
template<bool>
struct static_assertion;

template<>
struct static_assertion<true> {};
```

Though that has the drawback of not having a message associated to it.

After a bit of searching through StackOverflow, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980012/boost-static-assert-without-boost) which had a similar answer to mine and a bunch of alternatives for doing it without boost.

Comment: You can't beat [the one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14621998/412080) though.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I wasn't trying to one-up your answer. It's just the way I would have done it.

Comment: Thanks. That question has an answer similar to Maxim's, with macros

Answer (score 3):

This is basically Maxim's answer with a little more convenient interface. I have taken it from [here](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/9ef33c939e875ab63d60abe2a53fe05e103f7915/include/armadillo_bits/arma_static_check.hpp). Nice thing about it is that the use of templates prevents the user from passing a non-compile-time-constant value as the condition.

```
template<bool Is_Condition_Met>
struct Static_assert_cpp98
{
  static void apply() {static const char junk[ Is_Condition_Met ? 1 : -1 ];}
};

template<>
struct Static_assert_cpp98<true>
{
  static void apply() {}
};

#define STATIC_ASSERT_CPP98(condition) Static_assert_cpp98<condition>::apply()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add call to the method in question (a.foo();), the static assert will fail (just then the method will be compiled). You do know that you should not static assert on run time values like "k" I presume.

Comment: Yes, but I assumed (wrongly) that the compiler would see the value of k (like it sees when `bar` is called)

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo(const int k)
{
  STATIC_ASSERT( k > 9, error_msg );
  return k+5;
}
```

Static assertions only work with compile-time constant expressions.

`k` is not a compile-time constant expression.

Non-type template parameters are compile-time constant expressions during template instantiation, so you could adapt your code thus:

```
template <int K>
int foo()
{
  STATIC_ASSERT( K > 9, error_msg );
  return K+5;
}
```