# typedef char in a macro

Tags: c++, macros, dlib

I am reading the machine learning library dlib which is written in C++. I came across a code in a [header file](http://dlib.net/dlib/assert.h.html) which defines a bunch of macros. I have difficulties understanding the following code

```
#ifndef BOOST_JOIN
#define BOOST_JOIN( X, Y ) BOOST_DO_JOIN( X, Y )
#define BOOST_DO_JOIN( X, Y ) BOOST_DO_JOIN2(X,Y)
#define BOOST_DO_JOIN2( X, Y ) X##Y
#endif
//  a bunch of other code

namespace dlib
{
template <bool value> struct compile_time_assert;
template <> struct compile_time_assert<true> { enum {value=1};  };
// a bunch of other definitions
}

#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(expression) \
    DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED typedef char BOOST_JOIN(DLIB_CTA, __LINE__)[::dlib::compile_time_assert<(bool)(expression)>::value]
```

what I do not understand is that

1. what does the last line in the above code do?
2. `typedef char` here is so weird, I don't understand it at all.
3. After substitution for `BOOST_JOIN`, it becomes `DLIB_CTA__LINE__[1]`, why it is an array? Is it legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a C++03 static assert, or at least the workaround used to simulate it.

The following defines a struct only if `value` is true, else the type is not defined.

```
template <bool value> struct compile_time_assert;
template <> struct compile_time_assert<true> { enum {value=1};  };
```

Which means `compile_time_assert<true>::value` is perfectly correct, but `compile_time_assert<false>::value` is a compilation error since `compile_time_assert<false>` is not defined.

Now, the core of the assert:

```
DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED typedef char BOOST_JOIN(DLIB_CTA, __LINE__) ::dlib::compile_time_assert<(bool)(expression)>::value]
```

This defines a typedef on a `char` array of size 1, only if `expression` evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, then there is a compile time error and the name of the typedef is a hint about the error.

Note that there are some variants of this. Some use a negative or null size instead of a compilation error, ie they define the following:

```
template <> struct compile_time_assert<false> { enum { value = -1 };  };
```

But actually there is a way concise formulation of this (you can see it [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621968/how-to-do-static-assert-with-macros)):

```
typedef char static_assert_something[expression ? 1 : -1];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What does `DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED` do here between `COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(expression)` and `typedef`?

Comment: Probably something compiler specific to disable the warning about unused typedef (because you normally won't use this typedef, and some compilers warn about it).

Comment: but dlib is the library name, so putting `DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED` between `COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(expression)` and `typedef`, I don't understanding how it is syntactically right.

Comment: `DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED` is a macro. It could be `#define DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED` (so this would be replaced by nothing) or `#define DLIB_NO_WARN_UNUSED some-compiler-magic`.