# Why does this static assert not work?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, static-assert

I am trying to use a pre-C++11 static assert. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621968/how-to-do-static-assert-with-macros) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174356/ways-to-assert-expressions-at-build-time-in-c/174441#174441) question, but somehow I cant get it running:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(x) \
    do { \
        const static char dummy[(x)?1:-1] = {0};\
    } while(0)

struct bar {
    int value;
    template<typename T> void setValue(T x);
};
template<typename T> void bar::setValue(T x) { STATIC_ASSERT(1==0); }
template<> void bar::setValue(int x) { value = x;}

int main(){
    bar b;
    int c = 1;
    b.setValue(c);    
}
```

Compiling this (gcc) results in

> error: size of array 'dummy' is negative

I would expect this error to apprear only if I call `setValue` with anything other than `int`. I also tried other proposed solutions, but with more or less the same result: The error is there even if I dont instantiate the template with anything other than `int`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just curious, you know you don't have to use template at all in such case, and simply write it with `int` type? (It's still interesting question and answer for educational reasons, but I hope your real usage is not as trivial :) ).

Comment: @Ped7g well, in fact my real usage is as trivial as the example. I want to make absolutely sure that the function is called with parameter of the correct type and no conversion takes place. Whether this is good approach or not I am not yet sure, but thats not a discussion for here. I will put it on codereview...

Comment: look up the explict keyword

Comment: @UKMonkey as I understood `explicit` it allows me to avoid conversions of one particular type (whose code I wrote) but I dont see how this would help to avoid conversions taking place for the parameter of one particular function (e.g. `double` to `int`). Moreover `explicit` is C++11 but I am looking for a C++03 solution

Comment: explictit works in C98 for constructors; and would allow you to do something like
template<class T> X {
  X(explicit T);
  &T operator ();
}

The joy of this is that compiler errors would then say it couldn't convert <type> to <type> if you did something wrong

Comment: @UKMonkey sorry I dont see how this could help. My real code looks actually quite similar to the one posted here, ie a setter that should issue a compiler error for any other than the correct type. Do you maybe mean that my `setValue` should take a `X<int>` as parameter?

Comment: @UKMonkey: What is "C98"?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a template is invalid for every instantiation, then the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. GCC is therefore perfectly valid in giving you an error here, as the primary template for `setValue` is invalid no matter what the template argument is.

The way to solve this issue is to make the `STATIC_ASSERT` expression dependent on a template parameter. One option is to make a `dependent_false` template class, like this:

```
template <typename T> struct dependent_false 
{ const static bool value = false; };

template<typename T> void bar::setValue(T x) 
{ STATIC_ASSERT(dependent_false<T>::value); }
```

Comment: "If a template is invalid for every instantiation, then the program is ill-formed" even if there is a specialization that is not ill-formed?

Comment: ok, got it, but it feels a bit strange that your hack is working. If the compiler would be "clever enough" he could still realize that the template is illformed for any T

Comment: That's what two-phase lookup is about. Non-dependent calls are checked in phase 1

Comment: @tobi303 What if someone defines a specialization of `dependent_false` for some `T` and gives it a `... value = true;`? You don't know until instantiation time whether `value` is still `false`, or even if it exists at all.

Comment: @TartanLlama well, now I am getting confused, what if someone defines a specialization of `setValue` for some `T` that is not ill-formed.... that also didnt work. I will have to do so more research to understand this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @tobi303 The difference is that the primary template for `setValue` is invalid no matter what happens, so the standard lets compilers fail-fast in order to diagnose what could well be bad code. Consider a library template class which is invalid regardless of the template arguments; it's very helpful for a compiler to be able to diagnose that without ever having to instantiate it.

Comment: If at the end of the translation unit, no specialization of `dependent_false` exist that *could* possible make `value` true, your program is still *"ill-formed; NDR"*, although implementations don't go to that length in testing this. For maximal safety, you should add a specialization like `template<> struct dependent_false<bool> { static const bool value = true; }`.

Comment: I'm skimming the C++03 standard but I can't find the proof of this.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I guess you could even do something like `template<> struct dependent_false<class dummy> { const static bool value = true; };` to avoid future issues.