# How to allow only iterators with a ceratin value_type?

Tags: c++, iterator, typechecking, c++98, static-assert

I want to write a class that takes a pair of iterators as parameters to the constructor, but I dont know how to raise an error at compile-time when those iterators' `value_type` doesn't match an expected type. This is what I tried using `typeid`:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    std::vector<double> data;
    template <typename IT>
    foo(IT begin, IT end){
        typedef int static_assert_valuetype_is_double[
               typeid(typename IT::value_type) == typeid(double) ? 1 : -1
        ];
        std::cout << "constructor called \n";
        data = std::vector<double>(begin,end);
    }    
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x(5);
    foo f(x.begin(),x.end()); // double: ok

    std::vector<int> y(10);
    foo g(y.begin(),y.end()); // int: should not compile
}
```

Note that in this case, `int` to `double` would be fine, but thats just an example and in the real code the types have to match exactly. To my surprise in both cases, the constructor works without errors (there is only a warning about the unused typedef). Does the `-1` sized array static assert trick not work when the typedef is declared inside a method? **How do I produce an error when `IT::value_type` is the wrong type?**

PS: would be nice if there was an easy C++98 solution, but if this gets too complicated, I could also accept a C++11 solution.

Comment: `double*` is a valid iterator whose value type is obviously `double`, yet `double*` has no nested `double*::value_type`. I think you need `typeid(*begin)`

Comment: @MSalters sorry, if i wasnt clear in my question. I am mainly concerned about std containers and their iterators. If a solution excludes some exotic iterators, thats not a problem

Comment: Well, pointers aren't exotic, and they are the natural iterators of arrays. See `std::begin(MyArray)`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the constructor should use an initializer list instead of assigning a new value to the (default-constructed) vector in the constructor body. So: `foo(IT begin, IT end) : data(begin, end) { /* static assert goes here */ }`. In general, use the initializer list for all members unless there's a really good reason to delay setting the right values.

Comment: @PeterBecker i usually always do that, no idea why I didnt do it here. Actually it makes me nervous if a constructors body is anything different than `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern C++, you could have used [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type, double>,
     "wrong iterator");
```

See also [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits): an iterator `it` is not guaranteed to have a `value_type` typedef, and one should use `std::iterator_traits<it>::value_type` instead.

In C++ 98, `is_same` is trivial to implement, `static_assert` needs a [negative-size array trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621998/5470596) or the [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

Comment: Might wanna show how to implement it, since this is tagged C++98. Or mention boost.

Comment: @StoryTeller `is_same` isnt the problem in C++98, i think I could manage that, but my c++98 static assert seems to fail

Comment: @StoryTeller that's right but... it's been years since I haven't do a static_assert-ike in c++98 :/

Comment: @user463035818 - Fail how? Your version fails I reckon because of `typeid`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I will try a c++98 with `is_same` instead of `typeid`, maybe thats the problem

Comment: @user463035818 `is_same_v` is defined as `is_same<...>::value` ;) great saving of typing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++98 compliant way to implement it.....

First the fun part: Implementing a `is_same` is rather straightforward

```
template <typename T,typename U> struct is_same_type { static const bool value; };
template <typename T,typename U> const bool is_same_type<T,U>::value = false;
template <typename T> struct is_same_type<T,T> { static const bool value; };
template <typename T> const bool is_same_type<T,T>::value = true;
```

Now the not-so-fun part (C++11 really helps to statically assert without causing coworkers raising some eyebrows):

```
struct foo {
    std::vector<double> data;
    template <typename IT>
    foo(IT begin, IT end) : data(begin,end) {
        typedef int static_assert_valuetype_is_double[
             is_same_type<double,typename IT::value_type>::value ? 1 : -1
        ];
        std::cout << "constructor called \n";
    }

};

int main(){
    std::vector<double> x(5,2.3);
    foo f(x.begin(),x.end());
    for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = f.data.begin(); it != f.data.end();++it) std::cout << *it << " ";
    //std::vector<int> y(10,3);
    //foo g(y.begin(),y.end());  // THIS FAILS (AS EXPECTED)        
}
```

As pointed out by others, I should actually be using `std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type` as not every iterator has a `value_type`. However, in my case I rather want to restrict the possible iterators to a small set and disallowing iterators without a `value_type` isnt a problem in my specific case.

Also note that the code in the question assigned to the member, while it is of course better to use the initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that works in C++98 and later.....

```
#include <iterator>

template<class T> struct TypeChecker
{};

template<> struct TypeChecker<double>
{
     typedef double valid_type;
};

template <typename IT>
    void foo(IT begin, IT end)
{
      typename TypeChecker<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type>::valid_type type_checker;
      (void)type_checker;

        // whatever
}
```

Instantiations of `foo()` will succeed for any for an iterator for which `value_type` is `double`, and fail to compile otherwise.

The premise is that `TypeChecker<x>` does not have a `valid_type` for any `x` other than `double`, but we attempt to instantiate an instance of that type in `foo()`.     The `(void)type_checker` prevents warnings, from some compilers about a variable that is never used, for valid types.