# Template distinguish between signed and unsigned

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

If have written a template function and the code only work correct if the template type is unsinged. 
Now I search for a way to prevent the fumction from compiling with signed types, without C++11.

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    T a=0;
    return a<<1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::is_signed` is only available since C++11, however before you can use [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_signed).

As `static_assert` is also C++11, you have to use something else, eg the trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621998/4117728):

> ```
> typedef int static_assert_something[something ? 1 : -1];
> ```

Comment: Yes, this will do nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Without library: for signed types, `~T(0) < T(0)` but for unsigned types, `~T(0) > T(0)`. These are compile-time constants. See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57970643/15416) how to turn that into an error.