# Weird type assignment for array index in C++

Tags: c++, casting, variable-length-array

Hi I have a sample program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = -5;
    int arr[a];
    std::cout << "Size of arr: " << sizeof(arr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am getting the output of 17179869164.

My question is that the array size value should not accept negative values! and if I try giving a[-5], it throws an error. but now how am I getting the output of 17179869164.

I have my assumption too, the -5 is converted to an unsigned int value of 4294967291 and the total size is given as 17179869164 = 4294967291 * 4(size of int).

So I wanted to know why the compiler is typecasting signed int to unsigned int and not throwing a compile-time error. I needed a clear understanding of how the compiler is executing that piece of code?

Comment: Your program is invalid C++ (no matter the value of `a`), because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the info i didnt know this. But if i execute it has a complete C program with changes i get size as -20% in gcc , But shouldn't give it as a compiler error for providing negative value?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Visual Studio 2019 does throw compile errors for both the variable length array (as pointed out by @Someprogrammerdude), and, once you fix that, for `a` being negative.

Comment: @Frodyne i am using Visual studio code with g++ and gcc compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++, Variable Length Arrays are not provide by the standard, but may be provided by compiler extension. For C, the short answer is the standard converts the value to a positive integer value unless it is a constant expression -- in your case resulting in the use of the unsigned value (use of the two's compliment value as a positive value). Specifically:

> [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array
>   declarators(p5)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p5)
>
> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant
>   expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope,
>   it is treated as if it were replaced by *; otherwise, each time it is
>   evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

It is something called undefined behavior. To catch that kind of bug you could use the help of a static analyser.

Someone else asked something similar here:
[Declaring an array of negative length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3783282/10144903)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some interesting behavior in [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jN-efF).

I took you code and added a second copy where `a` is declared constant:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
    int a = -5;
    int arr[a];
    std::cout << "Size of arr: " << sizeof(arr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int bar() {
    const int a = -5;
    int arr[a];
    std::cout << "Size of arr: " << sizeof(arr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Then I threw GCC, Clang, and MSVC at them.](https://godbolt.org/z/jN-efF)

As far as I know, GCC and Clang both support variable length arrays (VLAs) as an "extra feature", and they both ate `foo` without a single complaint. Whereas MSVC, who does not support VLAs, complained.

On the other hand, none of them accepted `bar` on account of `a` being negative.

As for why GCC and Clang can't tell that `a`is negative in `foo`, that I will leave as a question for people more versed in compiler guts than I.